# how can You can assign the 'Lightning Experience User' permission to a set of users

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

how can You can assign the 'Lightning Experience User' permission to a set of users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Lightning Experience User" permission can be assigned either through a profile or a permission set.

**Profile** - gives the permission based on the profile - *all users with the profile have the permission*
Setup > Home > Users > Profiles > *The Profile's Name* > Edit > Administrative Permissions > Check Lightning Experience User > Save

**Permission Set** - gives the permission based on user - *select exactly which individuals get the permission*
Setup > Home > Users > Permission Sets > New > *Name the permission set* > Save > System Permissions > Edit > Lightning Experience User > Save > Manage Assignments > Add Assignments > *Select the users* > Assign > Done

Once you've assigned the permissions, make sure you activate the lightning experience for the org
Setup > Lightning Experience > *Skip to the end* > Enable > Finish Enabling Lightning Experience

Comment: Do we need to enable `Lightning Experience User` permission for users in case we are displaying Lightning Web Component in classic using lightning out?